# Removing duplicate elements in XML

Tags: c#, xml

My project requires a functionality to convert the input XML file into DataTable.
I am using the following code to do that.

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
 dataSourceFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
 ds.ReadXml(dataSourceFileStream);
 dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

This works quiet right unless the input XML has duplicate elements, for eg, if the XML file is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<DocumentElement>
 <data>
   <DATE>27 September 2013</DATE>
   <SCHEME>Test Scheme Name</SCHEME>
   <NAME>Mr John</NAME>
   <SCHEME>Test Scheme Name</SCHEME>
  <TYPE>1</TYPE>
 </data>
</DocumentElement>
```

As you can see above, the element **SCHEME** appears twice. when this kind of XML file comes `ds.ReadXml(dataSourceFileStream);` fails to return right data table.

Any better way to handle this?

Comment: Try using ReadXml(stream, XmlReadMode.IgnoreSchema.

Comment: You want to convert any input XML file into DataTable? If so, then this is not very good idea because XML contains hierarchical data

Comment: @Carra I tried that one. It doesn't work either.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, We are not converting any kind of xml file, we have accepted on having a file with only one level hierarchy those will be perfectly valid to convert to row and column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to fix the XML first. You can do this by using the XDocument and associated classes. But first you need to create a EqualityComparer which compares two XElements based on their name:

```
    public class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<XElement>
    {
        public bool Equals(XElement x, XElement y)
        {
            return x.Name == y.Name;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(XElement obj)
        {
            return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Now try this:

```
        var comparer = new MyEqualityComparer();

        XDocument.Load(dataSourceFileStream);

        var doc = XDocument.Parse(data);

        var dataElements = doc.Element("DocumentElement").Elements("data");
        foreach (var dataElement in dataElements)
        {
            var childElements = dataElement.Elements();
            var distinctElements = childElements.Distinct(comparer).ToArray();
            if (distinctElements.Length != childElements.Count())
            {
                dataElement.Elements().Remove();
                foreach (var item in distinctElements)
                    dataElement.Add(item);
            }
        }

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            doc.Save(writer);

            stream.Seek(0, 0);

            var ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            var mode = ds.ReadXml(stream);
            var dt = ds.Tables[0];      
        }
```

That would be a quick workaround to your problem. But i strongly suggest to encourage the data provider to fix the XML

Comment: Thank you, But is there a way we can achieve the same using LINQ?

Comment: How do you mean that? meaning a one-liner which is doing everything you need?

Comment: Yes, somewhat like inline Linq statement, just curious. Anyway tripping username. :)

Comment: well the base logic is in that foreach loop. all the other things around are used to get the string/stream into a XDocument and vice versa.
Another alternative would be to write a custom XmlTextReader and skip the duplicate elements.

Comment: Thanks mate, due to the time limit, I have already coded as in this answer. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. as stated in my previous comment, you can create your own XmlTextReader which patches/ignores some elements. The idea is, that this reader checks if he has already read an element within the same depth. If it is the case, advance to the end element.

```
    class MyXmlReaderPatcher : XmlTextReader
    {
        private readonly HashSet<string> _currentNodeElementNames = new HashSet<string>();

        public MyXmlReaderPatcher(TextReader reader) : base(reader)
        { }

        public override bool Read()
        {
            var result = base.Read();

            if (this.Depth == 1)
            {
                _currentNodeElementNames.Clear();
            }
            else if (this.Depth==2 && this.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (_currentNodeElementNames.Contains(this.Name))
                {
                    var name = this.Name;

                    do {
                        result = base.Read();
                        if (result == false)
                            return false;
                    } while (this.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement && this.Name != name);

                    result = this.Read();
                }
                else
                {
                    _currentNodeElementNames.Add(this.Name);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

All you have to do is to link the new reader in between your ds.ReadXml() and your file stream:

```
        var myReader = new MyXmlReaderPatcher(dataSourceFileStream);

        var ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        var mode = ds.ReadXml(myReader);
        var dt = ds.Tables[0];
```